# PHP include warnings

Tags: php, include, warnings, require

I Have 2 PHP-files.

Source/DAO/WinkelwagenDAO.php

Here I:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/iTBee/Model/WinkelwagenItem.php');
```

Then I have:
Source/Model/WinkelwagenItem.php -> Getters and setters

Now on an `onchange` event in JQuery I do an Ajax-Request to the WinkelwagenDAO file, Catch this request in the DAO file and call the appropriate function -> `UpdateAantal()`

Catch:

```
if(isset($_POST['function'])) {
    $action = $_POST['function'];

    switch ($action) {
        case 'UpdateAantal' :
            echo "\nAan te passen aantal voor ProductId: " . $_POST['productId'] . " gebruik functie: " . $_POST['function'] . " set aantal naar: " . $_POST['Aantal'];
            WinkelwagenDAO::UpdateAantal($_POST['productId']);
    }
}
```

`UpdateAantal()` function:

```
public static function UpdateAantal($productId) {

        if (isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"])) { //COOKIE EXISTS?
            $Array = self::getWinkelwagenItems();

            $index = 0; //positie bijhouden

            foreach ($Array as $product) {
                if ($productId == $Array[$index]->getProductId()) {
                    //echo $productId . " == " . $Array[$index]->getProductId();

                    $Array[$index]->setAantal($_POST['Aantal']);
                    $SerializeArray = serialize($Array);
                    setcookie("winkelwagen", $SerializeArray);

                    break; //Quit if match
                } else {
                    $index++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "This cookie did not exist";
        }
    }
```

Seems that I can not access the getters from WinkelwagenItem php class because include_once not working correctly. Although I think the path is correct? Also reason why I use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

When I do this I get an error in the console and 2 warnings:

> **Warning**:  include_once(./DAO/ProductDAO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iTBee/Model/WinkelwagenItem.php** on line **2**
>
> **Warning**:  include_once(): Failed opening './DAO/ProductDAO.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.6/lib/php') in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iTBee/Model/WinkelwagenItem.php** on line **2**
>
> **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iTBee/Model/WinkelwagenItem.php:2) in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iTBee/DAO/WinkelwagenDAO.php** on line **137**

Answer (score 0):

The warnings say that the failed include is the second line of the /iTBee/Model/WinkelwagenItem.php file. This include tries to find a ./DAO/ProductDAO.php file, which doesn't exist. You should search in WinkelwagenItem.php to solve this issue. You didn't post that code here.
The remarks of your question are irrelevant to the problem.